# Automatic download of created file in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My Sencha Touch 2 application has an 'Export' button, which creates an Excel file with the data of the selected offer.
After the user clicks the button, i want the (server side) export process to be started, and, once completed, the user to be prompted to select a filename and location, OR that the file is automatically downloaded. How do i do that? Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1):

For Excel specifically I'm not 100% sure, but this might help you get started or if a CSV is acceptable...

I'm sure you could pass the file reference to a var instead of the string but I have yet to try it.

If you paste the js below into the console you can see how this works. Pretty basic. Maybe try the returned value from the server to see if that works then if it does you can build a function around it to happen when needed.

```
csvHeading = 'HA, HB, HC, HD \n';

csvData    = 'r3a, r3b, r3c, r3d \n' +
             'r2a, r2b, r2c, r2d';

CSVFile = csvHeading + csvData;

window.location = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(CSVFile);
```